# Looping arrays to obtain data

Tags: php, arrays

I make a call to an API to return a list of Jobs.  The output I get is like the following

```
SimpleXMLElement {#357 ▼
  +"Jobs": SimpleXMLElement {#368 ▼
    +"Job": array:13 [▼
      0 => SimpleXMLElement {#371 ▼
        +"ID": "J000006"
        +"Name": "HTML Website"
        +"Client": SimpleXMLElement {#387 ▶}
        +"Budget": "5000.00"
        +"State": "In Progress"
        +"StartDate": "2016-03-31T00:00:00"
        +"DueDate": "2016-03-31T00:00:00"
      }
      1 => SimpleXMLElement {#372 ▶}
      2 => SimpleXMLElement {#373 ▶}
      3 => SimpleXMLElement {#374 ▶}
      4 => SimpleXMLElement {#375 ▶}
      5 => SimpleXMLElement {#376 ▶}
    ]
  }
}
```

I am now trying to get the Quote related to a Job.  So I make an API call to get a List of Quotes which produces something like this

```
SimpleXMLElement {#358 ▼
  +"Quotes": SimpleXMLElement {#366 ▼
    +"Quote": array:12 [▼
      0 => SimpleXMLElement {#369 ▼
        +"ID": "Q0019"
        +"Type": "Quote"
        +"State": "Accepted"
        +"Name": "HTML Website"
        +"Budget": "5000.00"
        +"LeadID": "1232718"
        +"Date": "2016-04-21T00:00:00"
        +"ValidDate": "2016-05-19T00:00:00"
        +"Amount": "1950.00"
        +"AmountTax": "390.00"
        +"AmountIncludingTax": "2340.00"
        +"Client": SimpleXMLElement {#384 ▶}
      }
      1 => SimpleXMLElement {#370 ▶}
      2 => SimpleXMLElement {#371 ▶}
      3 => SimpleXMLElement {#372 ▶}
      4 => SimpleXMLElement {#373 ▶}
      5 => SimpleXMLElement {#374 ▶}
    ]
  }
}
```

So I now have two XMLElements, I am now trying to create an array which has the following

```
Job -> ID
Job -> Name
Job -> Client
Quote -> Amount
Quote -> AmountTax
Quote -> AmountIncludingTax
```

So I create an empty array

```
$finalArray = array();
$iterator = 0;
```

With the XML above, the thing which can match a Quote to a Job is the Name attribute.  So I start looping the Jobs and Quotes to fill up 
my array with the data I need

```
foreach ($currentJobsXML->Jobs->Job as $job) {
    $seconditerator = 0;
    foreach($jobsQuoteXML->Quotes->Quote as $quote) {
        if((string)$quote->State == 'Accepted') {
            if ((string)$job->Name == (string)$quote->Name) {
                $finalArray[$iterator]['TEST'][$seconditerator] = array(
                    'Job ID' => (string)$job->ID,
                    'Project Name' => (string)$job->Name,
                    'Client' => (string)$job->Client->Name,
                    'Quote Exc VAT' => (string)$quote->Amount,
                    'VAT Amount' => (string)$quote->AmountTax,
                    'Total Amount' => (string)$quote->AmountIncludingTax
                );
                $seconditerator++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the above code, I only ever appear to get one output in my array

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "TEST" => array:1 [▼
      0 => array:6 [▼
        "Job ID" => "J000006"
        "Project Name" => "HTML Website"
        "Client" => "Prospect 1"
        "Quote Exc VAT" => "1950.00"
        "VAT Amount" => "390.00"
        "Total Amount" => "2340.00"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

There are quite a lot of Quotes which have been accepted which have the same name as a Jobs name, so I should be getting all of this data
too.

With the above code, why is my data being overwritten?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are forgetting to increment your `$iterator`

```
foreach ($currentJobsXML->Jobs->Job as $job) {
    $seconditerator = 0;
    foreach($jobsQuoteXML->Quotes->Quote as $quote) {
        if((string)$quote->State == 'Accepted') {
            if ((string)$job->Name == (string)$quote->Name) {
                $finalArray[$iterator]['TEST'][$seconditerator] = array(
                    'Job ID' => (string)$job->ID,
                    'Project Name' => (string)$job->Name,
                    'Client' => (string)$job->Client->Name,
                    'Quote Exc VAT' => (string)$quote->Amount,
                    'VAT Amount' => (string)$quote->AmountTax,
                    'Total Amount' => (string)$quote->AmountIncludingTax
                );
                $seconditerator++;
            }
        }
    }
    $iterator++;
}
```

I dont actually think you really need that `$seconditerator` either, if you just use `[]` it will automatically increment that array like this

```
foreach ($currentJobsXML->Jobs->Job as $job) {
    //$seconditerator = 0;
    foreach($jobsQuoteXML->Quotes->Quote as $quote) {
        if((string)$quote->State == 'Accepted') {
            if ((string)$job->Name == (string)$quote->Name) {
                //$finalArray[$iterator]['TEST'][$seconditerator] = array(
                $finalArray[$iterator]['TEST'][] = array(
                    'Job ID' => (string)$job->ID,
                    'Project Name' => (string)$job->Name,
                    'Client' => (string)$job->Client->Name,
                    'Quote Exc VAT' => (string)$quote->Amount,
                    'VAT Amount' => (string)$quote->AmountTax,
                    'Total Amount' => (string)$quote->AmountIncludingTax
                );
                //$seconditerator++;
            }
        }
    }
    $iterator++;
}
```